# NSFetchResultController - one-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

i have four tables. This is my table structure

Master >---->> Projects >---->> Tasks >----> Document

I am using NSFetchResultController to fetch objects from Database. Tasks are loaded in the tableview based on number of tasks for the projects. (for now there is only one project)

i can use following code to get the task objects

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Tasks" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"taskId" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

 NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

which returns the number of Tasks and i can use like this.

```
id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

But i need to use from top level objects like Master -- >> Projects -->> Tasks. How can i implement top level objects instead of using "Tasks" in FetchResultController.

i.e,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"Master" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

I don't have any id in master to sort. Master has one - many relationship with Projects.

Comment: So what's the actual problem here? Fetching tasks or sorting them?

Comment: i need to fetch like this master.projects.tasks instead of using tasks

Comment: Yes you are right, you can do that from the relationship that you have set up.. I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: in the above qn, i am setting "Task" entity in fetch request. so that "theFetchedResultsController" return the task objects. but i need master object. i can set a master entity in NSFetchRequest. but i don't have a key in master for sort descriptors. How can i set a "MAster" entity for FetchRequest w/o sort descriptor

Comment: You mean to say you don't have any attributes at all in Master entity?

Comment: yes..i dont have any attribute in master. but it has relationship with other entities. i need to use master as NSFetchResultController. But NSFetchResultController requires sort descriptor. but i dont have one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41844/discussion-between-suhas-and-iphone-guy)

Answer (score 0):

An entity without attributes is a bad design decision. Attributes are used to differentiate between various objects and not having that means that you practically have just one "Master" object and all "Project" instances will be related to this.

So, the first point I would like to make is remove the Master entity and only have "Project" and "Task"

If for some unknown reason you want to keep the "Master". Here's how you can access the single object.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Master"];
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The returned array will contain the master object using which you can access task as follows

```
Master *master = [results lastObject];
NSSet *tasks = master.projects.tasks;
```